Custom attribute validators won't run on abstract type
When using custom attribute validator inside a class that was derived from abstract class, the custom validator won't run.
My classes are something similar to this.
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public IList<AbstractClass> elements { get; init; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void SomeInternalFunction();
}

public class DerivedClass: AbstractClass
{

    [DataMember]
    [CustomValidation]
    public string value{ get; init; }

    public override void SomeInternalFunction(){...}

}

When creating instance of SomeClass with invalid DerivedClass.value, it appears to be always valid.
There are no issues with the CustomValidation on non-abstract classes or when directly creating instance of DerivedClass.
How can I make sure that the CustomValidation would run for the DerivedClass.value attribute when validating SomeClass instance?
Additional information:

Created an instance of SomeClass with invalid DerivedClass.value and running
Validator.TryValidateObject(SomeClass, new ValidationContext(SomeClass), null, true);

but it seems to always return true.
When in debug mode, it seems like the CustomValidation was never executed.

How are you creating an instance of SomeClass? It's declared as abstract.

My bad, fixed it. The class is not abstract.
